# What does Fire Keramik and Fire Lubline mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

There are a list of those nouns in [Standardized Ladder of Functional Programming](https://gist.github.com/chris-martin/0a0ccc382bd9ee07c8ee788d00f79108).

- Fire Keramik
- Fire Lubline
- Ice Skrig
- Fire Brushe
- Ice Thermagon

What are their meaning?

Comment: They seem to be titles or ranks and the lists that follow are the concepts and skills that have been master to justify that title or rank.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a question about English.

Comment: @HotLicks English is not my mother language, those words seem not to be meaningful when translating them to my mother language using Google translation. I googled them but didn't find more explaination for them. That's why I came here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are names for levels of competency. There's a [conversion chart](https://gist.github.com/gfixler/4545bc97ae785188ff1f1eb3d4880612) available, although it looks like the levels 0-5 for each skill ought to be the other way round.

> FIRE KERAMIK (formerly NOVICE)
>   FIRE LUBLINE (formerly ADVANCED BEGINNER)
>   ICE SKRIG (formerly COMPETENT)
>   FIRE BRUSHE (formerly PROFICIENT)
>   ICE THERMAGON (formerly EXPERT)
>
> — [Gary Fixler](https://gist.github.com/gfixler) on Github

If you're asking why those names were chosen, or what they actually refer to, this is the wrong site, although [Thermagon](https://sekaiju.fandom.com/wiki/Thermagon) is fairly easily found. The name doesn't seem to have much to do with programming ability.

> Thermagon is the mutant of Mountaglace Island. Like Sedipent, it is considered to be one of the hardest mutants to find. It is a Frost/Light type with Metal/Mythic coverage.
>
> "In due time, all will be frozen, and you'll only be floating away farther from the truth."
>
> — Sekaiju fandom

Comment: You know better.